# Magento Table Creation Using ORM Method

Tags: database, dataflow

I'm trying to create a new table in the Magento database using Magento's *Varien_Db_Ddl_Table*. Using fresh Magento 1.7.0.2 CE install for this.

I'm at a loss for syntax though. I'm trying to create a **BOOLEAN** field but I will also settle for a **TINYINT** if needs be. My **createTable** looks like this:

```
$table_one = $installer->getConnection()
->newTable($installer->getTable('my_module/table'))
->addColumn('id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
    'unsigned' => true,
    'identity' => true,
    'nullable' => false,
    'primary' => true,
), 'Entity id')
->addColumn('store_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 63, array(
    'nullable' => true,
    'default' => null,
), 'Store view id')
->addColumn('is_active', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TINYINT, 1, array(
    'nullable' => false,
    'default' => 1,
), 'Status')
->addColumn('created_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
    'nullable' => true,
    'default' => null, 
), 'Creation time')
->addIndex($installer->getIdxName(
    $installer->getTable('my_module/table'),
    array('store_id'),
    Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_INDEX
), 
array('store_id'), 
array('type' => Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_INDEX)
)
->setComment('My Module Table');
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table_one);
```

The field I'm struggling with is `is_active`. MySQL tries to set as AUTO-INCREMENT and NULL?!?

Can anyone set me straight please or point me to some useful docs? I found [these](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Varien/Varien_Db/Varien_Db_Ddl_Table.html), but no syntax guidelines really :(

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the most part, Magento internals handle initial table creation with raw SQL on setup:

**app/code/core/Enterprise/Cms/sql/enterprise_cms_setup/mysql4-install-1.6.0.0.0.php**

```
$installer->run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `{$installer->getTable('enterprise_cms/hierarchy_metadata')}` (
  `node_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `meta_first_last` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_next_previous` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_chapter` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_section` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pager_visibility` TINYINT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `pager_frame` SMALLINT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `pager_jump` SMALLINT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `menu_visibility` TINYINT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `menu_levels_up` TINYINT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `menu_levels_down` TINYINT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `menu_ordered` TINYINT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `menu_list_type` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`node_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ENTERPRISE_CMS_HIERARCHY_METADATA_NODE` FOREIGN KEY (`node_id`) REFERENCES `{$installer->getTable('enterprise_cms/hierarchy_node')}` (`node_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
");
```

You see the TINYINT type being added quite often via `addColumn` which is available through `getConnection()` in `$installer`:

**Mage/Core/Catalog/sql/catalog_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.7.72-0.7.73.php**

```
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('catalog/product_super_attribute_label'),
    'use_default', 'tinyint(1) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0 AFTER store_id');
```

Which is usually called on an existing table.

[There's nothing wrong with using TINYINT(1) as a boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/289759/582138). If you're dead set against the SHOW CREATE copy-pasta method of popuplating table schema with `$installer->run`, **avoid the setup woes you're having** and run the addColumn later **as an update in your module**:

**mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1:**

```
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('yourresource/model'),
    'is_active', 'TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0 AFTER store_id');
```

Comment: Thanks Phil, the update seems the logical move right now. Thx for the info!

Answer (score 7):

For future reference, the following syntax will add a **TINYINT(1)** field - for which **BOOLEAN** is a MySQL alias:

```
->addColumn('is_active', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_BOOLEAN, 1, array(
    'nullable' => false,
    'default' => 1,
), 'Status')
```

And the resulting field in MySQL:

```
Name, Type, Null, Default
is_active, tinyint(1), No, 1
```

Hope that helps a future visitor.